# How do Museums put text directly on the wall?

Tags: print-design, text, signage

Museums usually add text to the wall by a simple label/sign or vinyl cut lettering. But larger well funded museums use a different technique where the text appears to be directly transferred to the wall somehow. This is not using a vinyl sticker and is very high quality even at small text sizes.

Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very often museums will use a screen printing method to apply type to the walls, also in conjunction with other methods such as vinyl and hand painted murals traced with projectors.

Comment: Screen Printing is probably the answer. Is there a streamlined screen printing method that museums use for text? It seems like it would be quite labor intensive for 100 little artwork labels to be done using standard screen printing techniques.

Comment: Yes very labor intensive, Google is your friend user500665 - http://whitney.org/WhitneyStories/WordsOnWalls https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eVq0zp88GU

Comment: @MarkRead You should include those links and relevant details from them in your question itself, it'd make your answer a lot better!

Comment: I will edit later so the Answer is more useful, thanks for the reminder Zach